# Property injection not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ninject

I have two classes which depend on each other. Obviously, when I use ninject in the following way:

```
public Class Class1()
{
  private readonly class2;
  public Class1(IClass2 class2)
  {
    this.class2 = class2;
  }
}

public Class Class2()
{
  private readonly class1;
  public Class1(IClass1 class1)
  {
    this.class1 = class1;
  }
}
```

It results in a cyclic dependency.

I know that the way to solve this problem is property injection. But I tried this:

```
public Class Class1()
{
  private readonly class2;
  public Class1()
  {
  }
  [Inject]
  IClass2 Class2
  {
   get { return this.class2; }
   set { this.class2 = value; }
  }
}
```

in combination with this:

```
public Class Class2()
{
  private readonly class1;
  public Class1(IClass1 class1)
  {
    this.class1 = class1;
  }
}
```

And the reversed way, when I inject in the second one with property and in the first with constructor. Both of them result in a cyclic dependency. The third way, when I use property injection in both of them, results in a StackOverflow exception. What is the way to implement this type of injection? Keeping in mind that both of these are service classes.

Binding:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind(b => b
            .From(Assemblies.ProjectServices) // link to the services there
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .BindDefaultInterface());
        }
```

Comment: Property injection should solve the cyclic dependency, can you show us where is the exception thrown?

Comment: I have a controller, where I inject Class1 (it depends on it). When I try to initialize it throws the exception.

Comment: Can you show us the ninject kernel binding?

Comment: It is in the question.

Comment: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007302/ninject-cyclic-dependency-already-using-property-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can try to use other [Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) when you register Class1 and Class2 instead of the deafult one (`InTransientScope()`).
Something like this (I used singleton scope here for example):

```
 kernel.Bind<IClass1>().To<Class1>().InSingletonScope();
 kernel.Bind<IClass2>().To<Class2>().InSingletonScope();
```

Also I think that it will only work if you will use property injection for both classes and not only in one of them, you should try both options.

As a side note I do think that a cyclic dependency is a big hint that you are missing something in your design and you should condiser redesigning these classes.

Comment: Did you try using Singleton scope, What if actual program cannot work with Singleton instance, but need a unique object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I don't undertand what is the probelm, you can choose from the already existing scopes the one who answers yours needs and if thre isn't any you can create a custom one, the singleton scope was just for the example.